# WSUS Post-Installation error | Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I did a standard WSUS installation, now I'm trying to do the post-installation, but it's kept failing, I'm the administrator of the machine, and I've tried to do the installation again with a domain administrator account, but the post installation keeps failing with these logs:

> : 2017-07-18 11:58:00  Postinstall started
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Detected role services: Api, UI, WidDatabase, Services
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Start: LoadSettingsFromXml
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Start: GetConfigValue with filename=UpdateServices-Services.xml item=ContentLocal
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Value is true
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  End: GetConfigValue
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Start: GetConfigValue with filename=UpdateServices-Services.xml item=ContentDirectory
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Value is D:\Updates
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  End: GetConfigValue
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Content directory is D:\Updates
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Database roleservice is not installed
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  End: LoadSettingsFromXml
>   Post install is starting
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Start: Run
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Fetching WsusAdministratorsSid from registry store
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Value is S-1-5-21-4086084134-1731516386-1660926666-1001
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Fetching WsusReportersSid from registry store
>   2017-07-18 11:58:01  Value is S-1-5-21-4086084134-1731516386-1660926666-1002
>   2017-07-18 11:59:02  Configuring content directory...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:02  Configuring groups...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:02  Starting group configuration for WSUS Administrators...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:02  Found group in regsitry, attempting to use it...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Writing group to registry...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Finished group creation
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Starting group configuration for WSUS Reporters...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Found group in regsitry, attempting to use it...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Writing group to registry...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Finished group creation
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Configuring permissions...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Fetching content directory...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Fetching ContentDir from registry store
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Value is D:\Updates
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Fetching group SIDs...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Fetching WsusAdministratorsSid from registry store
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Value is S-1-5-21-4086084134-1731516386-1660926666-1001
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Fetching WsusReportersSid from registry store
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Value is S-1-5-21-4086084134-1731516386-1660926666-1002
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Creating group principals...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:05  Granting directory permissions...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:06  Granting permissions on content directory...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:06  Granting registry permissions...
>   2017-07-18 11:59:06  System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException: The process does not possess the 'SeSecurityPrivilege' privilege which is required for this operation.
>      at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.GetSecurityInfo(ResourceType resourceType, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections accessControlSections, RawSecurityDescriptor& resultSd)
>      at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
>      at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity..ctor(Boolean isContainer, ResourceType resourceType, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
>      at System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity..ctor(SafeRegistryHandle hKey, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections)
>      at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections includeSections)
>      at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ConfigurePermissions.GrantRegistryPermissions(IdentityReference identity, RegistryRights registryRights)
>      at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ConfigurePermissions.GrantRegistryPermissions()
>      at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.PostInstall.Run()
>      at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.PostInstall.Execute(String[] arguments)
>   Fatal Error: The process does not possess the 'SeSecurityPrivilege' privilege which is required for this operation.

If anyone has elderly experienced a similar issue and could help...

Comment: have you executed this command in "run as administrator" context ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That last log line tells you what the issue is - the account you're using to run the installer does not have all the permissions required to complete the install.

> Fatal Error: The process does not possess the 'SeSecurityPrivilege' privilege which is required for this operation.

Based on where we see it fail (on the `Granting registry permissions...` step), I would suspect a GPO or something on your domain locking down registry access, but I've seen this error pop up for other product installs around the `Manage auditing and Security log` rights, so it's hard to say for sure what the exact problem is.  I'd recommend running the installer again and monitoring the process with something like [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  That way you can determine exactly what file or registry key prompts the failure, and grant the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You should manually add an user account to the "Manage auditing and security log" in secpol.msc

Answer (score 1):

As above: "You should manually add an user account to the "Manage auditing and security log" in secpol.msc"

Some auditing software I used required messing with a GPO that specified a domain user to this security policy. By default the policy contains "Administrators", I put domain admins in there and ran the post-installation process as a domain admin.